# What is actually the value of UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum?

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm about setting up background fetch for an iOS application.

I do:

```
func application(
    application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?
    ) -> Bool {
        ...
        application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(
            UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
        ...
```

if I inspect and print `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` in the debugger it says `0` - what is the value actually ?

I tried looking through the api as well but no luck https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not specified by Apple how long `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` time is, however in practice it is around 10 minutes.

Comment: This constant is available on iOS7 and later.

Comment: How is around 10 minutes if this setting is available only for iOS 7+, according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationbackgroundfetchintervalminimum?language=objc?

Comment: Where do you guys got that number from? I don't see it anywhere in docs.

Comment: Been waiting way longer. Here is why it makes sense: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-when-your-app-is-terminated